# Android: How to declare global objects (textviews, buttons) and modify them with functions

Tags: android

I am able to create a global object like a button or textview but I am not able to use them in my functions.

I'd like to create a global textview or edittext view where I will be able to read and modify its contents with my functions.

This is an example, I created a textview under onCreate called "titles"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TextView titles = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Later in the same activity, I have a function that tries to modify its text, instead I get an error saying cannot resolve.

```
public void win(){

titles.setText("Second text to display!");

}
```

Comment: Put the titles variable as a member variable,instead of defining it inside the function. Also you said "global" not sure if you're using the right term for what you want. Global variables can be accessed anywhere in the application. If thats what you want then you need the "static" modifier.

Comment: What you did wasn't a global variable, it was a local variable.  Class scoped variables, like you want, need to be declared inside the class but outside all functions.  There is no such thing as a global variable in Java, although depending on what you want a static class variable or public class variable comes close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `TextView` outside `onCreate` to be able to access it from other functions.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView titles;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    titles = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Then use it from other functions and it will work

```
public void win(){

    titles.setText("Second text to display!");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variables at class level outside the onCreate:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView titles;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        titles = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView titles;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        titles = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```